# automatically show value when choose multiple checkbox in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'am newer. I get a problem at java.

How to doing and automatically value want i click multiple checkbox?
this is my java code.

public class StepsTaken extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView mtextView;
Button bSaveST, mBtn;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference reff;
```

// private ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   // private ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_steps_taken);

    //adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);


    Button mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    final TextView mtextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewAdd);

    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StepsTaken.this);

            String[] foods = new String[] {"Ayam goreng", "Ayam tandoori", "Burger", "Capati", "Ikan kembong ", "Karipap", "Nasi lemak ", "Nasi ayam ", "Nasi putih ", "Mee goreng ", "Mee Sup", "Telor goreng ","Popia goreng", "Pisang goreng", "Sandwich Sardin", "Tea", "Kopi", "Nescafe Ais", "Milo Ais", "Minuman Kotak"};
            int[] val1 = {0, 255, 220, 425, 300, 140, 180, 400, 300, 260, 660, 380, 110, 170, 180, 70, 0, 150, 150, 350, 300, 105};

            final boolean[] checkedFoods = new boolean[] {
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
                    false,
            };

            final List<String> foodList = Arrays.asList(foods);

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(foods, checkedFoods, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    checkedFoods[which] = isChecked;
                    String currentItem = foodList.get(which);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            builder.setCancelable(false);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click positive button

                for (int i = 0; i<checkedFoods.length; i++){
                    boolean checked = checkedFoods[i];
                    if (checked) {
                        mtextView.setText(mtextView.getText() + foodList.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click the negative button
                }
            });

            builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click the neutral button
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

so, how can i show the value when i click multiple checkbox? or maybe my code should add more source code?